CSS animations just stopped working on React
My css animations just stopped working and i have no idea why, this is a react project i'm working on to learn more about the framework, if someone knows why this happens it would help a lot, thanks.
Github repository (client branch)
video of animation working
video of animation not working
disable animation config
CSS code:
.wrong-animation {
  animation: wrong-animation 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94) both;
}

@keyframes wrong-animation {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.correct-animation {
  animation: correct-animation 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.085, 0.68, 0.53) both;
}

@keyframes correct-animation {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-1000px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.spawn-animation {
  animation: spawn-animation 200ms cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275) both;
}

@keyframes spawn-animation {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.5);
    transform-origin: bottom;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
    transform-origin: bottom;
  }
}

.correct-animation-filter {
  background-color: green !important;
  animation: correct-animation-filter 600ms cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94)
    both;
}

@keyframes correct-animation-filter {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.75;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.wrong-animation-filter {
  animation: wrong-animation-filter 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94)
    both;
}

@keyframes wrong-animation-filter {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

React code:
import "./index.scss";

const FlashCard = ({
  noun,
  nounGroup,
  submitAnswer,
  onAnimationEnd,
  flashcardAnimationClass,
  onAnimationStart,
  config,
}) => {
  let currentAnimation = flashcardAnimationClass;
  
  let filterAnimationClass = flashcardAnimationClass === "" ? "" : `${flashcardAnimationClass}-filter`;
  if (config.disableAnimations) currentAnimation = "";

  return (
    <div
      className={`flashcard shadow-drop-center ${currentAnimation}`}
      onAnimationEnd={onAnimationEnd}
      onAnimationStart={onAnimationStart}      
    >
      <div className={`flashcard__filter ${filterAnimationClass}`}></div>
      
      <div className="flashcard__head shadow-drop-bottom">
        <div
          className="image"
          id="flashcard__head__image"
          style={{
            backgroundImage: `url("/groups/${nounGroup.toLowerCase()}.jpeg")`,
          }}
        ></div>
      </div>

      <div className="flashcard__title-container">
        <h1 className="title">{noun}</h1>
        {!config.hideNounGroup && (
          <p className="subtitle">Group: {nounGroup}</p>
        )}
      </div>

      <div className="flashcard__button-container">
        <div
          className="masculine-button"
          onClick={() => submitAnswer("masculine")}
        >
          <span>Der</span>
        </div>
        <div
          className="feminine-button"
          onClick={() => submitAnswer("feminine")}
        >
          <span>Die</span>
        </div>
        <div className="neuter-button" onClick={() => submitAnswer("neuter")}>
          <span>Das</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default FlashCard;


I tried looking through the code and found nothing, i really don't know why it stopped working

If they worked fine before, did you check your config.disableAnimations value?

Hello. Yes, the config is set to false, i added a screenshot of it in the post
